# Are there any studies on correlations between eye movements and personality?

Tags: personality, eye-movement, preferences

I'm looking for scientific evidence for or against a notion that eye movements can be used as a cue to personality(traits).

- This may include notions like high extroversion individuals look more at other people, than do low extroversion individuals(?)
- Possible notions that high and low agreeablesness individuals prefer looking at different things.
- Big 5 correlations are preferred.
- Results should be valid for western cultures (cross cultural studies or studies on western culture populations)

The idea is that eye movements would tell you the person's preferences and thus something about the person's cognition.

(I'm looking for links to scientific reports here)